# How do I trap a bad URL in openURL swift

Tags: ios, swift2

If my url has a space at the end it crashes with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

I thought canOpenURL would trap for a bad URL but it doesn't.

```
if let strurl = cell.url{
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:strurl)!)) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:strurl)!);
    }
}
```

In my case a URL with an extra space at the end crashes it. I can trim white space, but what about anything else? Is there a proper way to trap for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are force unwrapping `NSURL` which causes the app to crash if it happens to be `nil`.  To check the validity of the URL you should be using `if let` on the URL itself as well.

```
if let strurl = cell.url,
   let url = NSURL(string: strurl) {
      if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
      }
}
```